# If $g$ is Borel measurable, then $Y = g(X_1, X_2)$ is $\sigma(X_1, X_2)$-measurable

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

I'm trying to prove **Proposition 1.17** from this [note](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/%7Eleveque/Lecture_Notes/APA_lecture_notes_1819.pdf), i.e.,

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$ be a measurable space and $X_1, X_2$ real-valued random variables. Let $g: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be Borel measurable and $Y = g(X_1, X_2)$. Then $Y$ is $\sigma(X_1, X_2)$-measurable, i.e., $\sigma(Y) \subset \sigma(X_1, X_2)$.

Could you have a check on my below attempt?

---

Let $B \in \mathcal B (\mathbb R)$. Then $g^{-1} (B) \in \mathcal B (\mathbb R^2)$ and
$$
\{Y \in B\} = \{(X_1, X_2) \in g^{-1} (B) \}.
$$

It suffices to prove that
$$
\mathcal A :=\{A \in \mathcal B (\mathbb R^2) \mid \{(X_1, X_2) \in A \} \in \sigma(X_1, X_2) \}.
$$
coincides with $\mathcal B (\mathbb R^2)$. However, this is true because $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathcal A$ contains the subbase $\{A \times B \mid A, B \text{ open in } \mathbb R\}$ of the product topology of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\sigma(X_1,X_2)$?

Comment: @copper.hat I mean by $\sigma(X_1,X_2)$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_1, X_2$, i.e., the smallest $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal G$ on $\Omega$ such that $X_1, X_2$ are $\mathcal G$-measurable.